# R - sweave - count words

Tags: r, sweave, word-count

I could not find a clear solution, so I would like to ask if there is some tool to count words (excluding R - latex code) in a .Rnw file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but `knitr::knit_filter()` is a function to exclude R code from an Sweave document, and return a character vector that only contain the prose, of which you can count the words with other tools (such as `wc`).